# Code is making a .o file but no .exe file when compiling

Tags: c++, makefile, linker, windows-subsystem-for-linux, clang++

I am attempting to compile a c++ project on WSL 2 with the make cmd using clang++ compiler.

I am getting the following message:

```
root@DESKTOP-1I1NU1L:/mnt/c/users/LaVision/source/Yoakum# make
clang++ -std=c++17 -stdlib=libc++ -I/usr/include/boost/ -o YOAKUM.exe driver.o
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lc++
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [Makefile:10: YOAKUM.exe] Error 1
```

Here is a copy of my make file:

```
  CC := clang++
  export CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH = /usr/include/c++/8 
  :/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/8

  FLAGS := -std=c++17 -stdlib=libc++ -I/usr/include/boost/

  all: YOAKUM.exe

  OBJECTS := driver.o
  YOAKUM.exe: $(OBJECTS)
     $(CC) $(FLAGS) -o YOAKUM.exe $(OBJECTS) 

 driver.o: driver.cpp driver.hpp configure.hpp Dust_State.hpp\
  configure.hpp System.hpp io_observers.hpp basic_forces.hpp\
  interaction_forces.hpp Vector.hpp
  $(CC) $(FLAGS) -c driver.cpp
```

I am using make version 4.2.1.
Clang version 7.0.1-8+deb10u2.

Any help would be very appreciated as I am a new dev and am absolutely stumped by this issue.

Comment: When linking you should use different options from what you feed the compiler, a `LDFLAGS` in addition to the `FLAGS` and used in place of `FLAGS` when invoking the linker.

Comment: Sorry if the answer is obvious, but what should I set FLAGS and LDFLAGS to?  Would this force me to change the places where I use FLAGS in the current make file?  @user4581301

Comment: Not obvious, but hard to be sure what options you need. I tried to address that, but I messed it up. What goes on LDFLAGS varies too much. You might not need any. But since you are including boost, you may need `LDFLAGS := -L<path to boost lib folder>` and maybe `a LIB := -l<boost library used>`. Then you get `$(CC) $(LDFLAGS) -o YOAKUM.exe $(OBJECTS) $(LIBS)`
`

Comment: Start by removing `$(FLAGS)` from `$(CC) $(FLAGS) -o YOAKUM.exe $(OBJECTS)` and see what the linker complains about.

Comment: And SOS... What operating system is that?

Comment: I am running Windows Subsystem for Linux 2.0 in windows 11. @user4581301

Comment: you probably need to install [libc++](https://packages.debian.org/buster/libc++1) package if you really want to use `-stdlib=libc++`. And I suppose the include paths you explicitly set `/usr/include/c++/8` are from gcc libstdc++. so, you either remove `-stdlib=libc++` and use libstdc++ library and headers or install and use `libc++` but do not mix.

Comment: You should never manually set C++ include path to something inside /usr/include/c++. If you think you need it, something is wrong with your setup. Which is the case here (libc++ is not installed).